# Actual file location of a WordPress featured image?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm generating a query for certain posts in 'Trash'. I can retrieve the featured image URL, but I'm looking for a way to get the featured image file location on the server.

```
# generate the query
foreach ( $query as $post ) {
    $thumbID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
    $thumbObj = get_post( $thumbID );
    $source_url = $thumbObj->guid;
    # how do I get the string "/path/to/wordpress/media/library/thumbnail.jpg" ?
}
```

I can't find any WordPress function that returns the actual featured image file location.

Comment: you mean something like this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src wp_get_attachment_image_src

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no wp function but its easy enough to make your own, e.g.

```
function return_image_path($thumbID) {

    $image= wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbID);
    $imagepath= str_replace(get_site_url(), $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], $image[0]);

    if($imagepath) return $imagepath;

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Very close, although the code assumes WordPress is installed in the root directory. However it did lead me to find the function wp_upload_dir() with a very similar solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
var_dump(get_attached_file($post_thumbnail_id));
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on David's answer, this worked for me:

```
function return_image_path($thumbID) {
                    $thumbID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
                    $image= wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbID);
                    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
                    $base_dir = $upload_dir['basedir'];
                    $base_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'];
                    $imagepath= str_replace($base_url, $base_dir, $image[0]);
                    if ( file_exists( $imagepath) ) return $imagepath;
                    return false;
}
```